# Basic jQuery navigation color change

Tags: jquery, hover, nav

I'm struggling to find an answer to arguably one of the most basic jquery questions:

I would like the following to change the 'a' elements background color to blue (I expect it's a simple syntax issue)

[I am aware this is best done in CSS, but I am trying to learn jquery]

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="">Make</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Me</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Blue</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul {
     list-style:none;
}

li {
     float:left;
}

a {
     display:block;
     text-decoration:none;
     background-color:red;
     height:40px;
     width:100px;
     margin-right:1px;
     text-align:center;
     line-height:40px;
     color:white;
}
```

jQUERY:

```
$('a').hover(function() {
    $('a').css('background-color', 'blue');
});
```

The jsFiddle is here:
http://jsfiddle.net/liquidengine/jRM2K/2/

Comment: The fiddle contains nothing useful.

Comment: Now the biggest problem with your fiddle is that you aren't including jQuery. But I suppose you've got all the answers you need already, so there's no need to bother fixing that now.

Comment: @PeteNorris - On the left hand side of your JSFiddle, you need to select a library (jQuery).

Comment: @ahren Aah. I knew it had something to do with some inherently stupid oversight on my part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing in your jsFiddle. You just need to look at the code and try and understand what it's trying to do. In your example, whenever an `a` is hovered, you are setting the color of *all* anchors to blue. Then you haven't tried to handle the mouseout event. Try something like this:

```
$('a').hover(function() {
   // set background colour of the hovered anchor
   $(this).css('background-color', 'blue');
}, function() {
   // remove background colour when hovered off
   $(this).css('background-color', '');
});
```

I know you said you don't want to use CSS because you want to learn jQuery, but this is a job for CSS. If you want to learn jQuery, try to build things that jQuery is required for. Because you should never, ever use jQuery to do this. And here's a hot tip: should you ever wish to change the colour of elements using jQuery (say, on click), at least use classes. Don't set the properties using jQuery. Example:

```
$('a').hover(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('hovered');
});
```

CSS:

```
a.hovered {
  background-color: blue;
  /* other styles here */
}
```

Comment: Yes, I appreciate that, but once I have this down I'm going to build this out to include transitions, drop menu's and all sorts. Hey I might even add a marquee.

Comment: @PeteNorris you can, and should do _all_ of that using CSS.

Comment: With your new example, it'd be easier to just write `$('a').hover(function() { $(this).toggleClass('hovered'); })`

Answer (score 0):

do:

```
$('a').hover(function() {
   $(this).css('backgroundColor', 'blue');
});
```

Updated [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jRM2K/1/)

Comment: You mean `background-color` ?

Comment: @jtheman you can use background-color or backgroundColor, both should work..! check the fiddle

Comment: Ah, I see. My advice would be to use the default css property though.

Comment: @jtheman jQuery can equally interpret the CSS and DOM formatting of multiple-word properties. For example, it understands and returns the correct value for both .css('background-color') and .css('backgroundColor')

Comment: Yes you're completely correct. However it can easily be confusing to mix CSS and DOM formatting therefore my "advice".